# Azure Provisioning - Without manual login

Tags: powershell, login-script, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I have a Powershell script which runs to set up Azure web apps, databases, etc. but before running the script, I have to do the following:

```
PS C:/> Login-AzureRmAccount
```

This pops up a GUI in which I have to manually add in my user, password, and my 2-factor authentication code. I eventually want to use that script as a part of a part of a build/deployment automation script.

I gleaned the following from a few articles about using a "service principal".

First I do:

```
PS C:\> Add-AzureRmAccount
```

In this call I have to put in my user, password, and authentication code

After that I have to do the following (even though I don't fully understand).

```
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "GGReal" -HomePage    "https://www.example.org/ggreal" -IdentifierUris     "https://www.example.org/ggreal" -Password "mysecretpass"

New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

This seems to work:

Then I try this, and it fails.

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId
```

I got the following error:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : AuthorizationFailed: The client jay@myemail.com' with object id '8ee9a6ec-yyyy-xxxx-xxxx-4ac0883f2a12' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/5ba06de5-xxxx-zzzz-yyyy-27f7d2c8bba6'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleAssignment], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

What do I have to do to enable a scripted authorization without manual intervention?

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Comment: No updates. I got swapped out for another work item. I'll be back to this eventually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception that it indicates that you don't has adequate permission to that. We can check active directory permissions following the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal). Our account needs to have `Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write` access to assign an AD app to a role. That means our account should be assigned to the 
[Owner role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#owner) or [User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) role. If not, please  ask your subscription administrator to add you to User Access Administrator role. How to add or change Azure administrator roles please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator).

After that please have a try to Automate login for Azure Powershell scripts with the following code.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

I also find some related documents about creating authentication and Built-in roles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#roles-in-azurel

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have permissions to assign that role to that serviceprincipal, you need appropriate rights. And those would be: `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` and scope `/subscriptions/5ba06de5-xxxx-zzzz-yyyy-27f7d2c8bba6`

You could either create a new [Custom Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles) and assign it to your account, or assign something like Subscription Admin (not sure if its the least possible approach, but you can retract it later) to your account.

Comment: Is that something my Azure administrator would do? I'm not the "boss" of our Azure account, but I have a lot of privileges.

Comment: Well, anyone with the required permissions, account you are logged in is clearly lacking those specific permissions