# Retrieve Azure Service Bus Shared Access Connection String via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus

It's possible to retrieve the access key to an Azure storage account using Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey from Powershell. How would I get hold of the access key to a shared access policy of an Azure Service Bus?

**More clarification**

This is what I get when I use the Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred

Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : ***redacted***
TenantId              : ***redacted***
SubscriptionId        : ***redacted***
CurrentStorageAccount : 

PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId ***redacted***

Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : ***redacted***
TenantId              : ***redacted***
SubscriptionId        : ***redacted***
CurrentStorageAccount : 


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey -ResourceGroup testresourcegroup -Name test-bus -AuthorizationRuleName SendPolicy
Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey -ResourceGroup testresourcegroup -Name    test-bus ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.Commands.Namespace.GetAzure RmServiceBusNamespaceKey


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName testresourcegroup -Name teststoragexxx

Key1                                                                                                        Key2                                                                                                   
----                                                                                                    ----                                                                                                   
***redacted***                ***redacted***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with *Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey*, but you can use *Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey*

> $resourceGroup = "myResourceGroup"
>   $serviceBusName ="myservicebusname"
>   $policyName = "policyname"
>
> Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -Name
>   $serviceBusName -AuthorizationRuleName $policyName

This will return the whole object, so you can pass it into a variable and get the keys or connection strings from that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When I try to run the command I get the error 'Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login'. 

However, I can successfully retrieve the keys for storage accounts in the same resource group using Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey. 

Any idea why it might think I'm not logged in?

Comment: You'll need to login to Azure using Login-AzureRMAccount (and possibly set the correct context with Set-AzureRmContext) in order to run that, without authenticating Azure doesn't know who you are or what subscription you're in.  I can't run Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey eithout authenticating either.

Comment: Yes - I've done both of those things. As I said, I can retrieve the keys for storage accounts in the subscription, but can't get the keys for the service bus.

Comment: I've modified the original post to demonstrate what happens when I try to use Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey

Comment: That's odd, running that exact sequence of commands returns both fine for me.  Are you running the latest version of Azure PowerShell?

Comment: I'm running Powershell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm on same OS and PShell version, `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureRm.ServiceBus` should tell you what version of that module you're running.  Also, try just running `Login-AzureRmAccount` without the credentials, there's a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3335) on GitHub related to some commands not working correctly when you pass in the service principal.

Comment: I've tried logging in with and without credentials, and I've tried two different subscriptions (one personal MSDN account and one corporate MSDN account). For some reason when I run `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureRm.ServiceBus`, the command returns 2 lines, both of which indicate AzureRM.ServiceBus version 0.0.2.

Comment: `VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.ServiceBus\.\Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.dll'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.ServiceBus\AzureRM.ServiceBus.psm1'.`

Comment: OK. After talking to our domain admins, it looks like this is some sort of AD problem - some sort of conflict of IDs with Office 365. Anyway, if I run the same command on a machine that's not joined to our domain, it all works fine. Thanks very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try to  login with tenantId and ServicePrincipal. I do a demo test about that, it works correctly for me.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred  -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

The following is may detail steps.

1 . We need to install service Bus module if it is not install.  More detail info about AzureRM.ServiceBus please refer to [document](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.ServiceBus/0.0.2).

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.ServiceBus
```

2.More detail info about  Automatically login script  please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190914/azure-provisioning-without-manual-login?answertab=active#tab-top).

3.Run the test script and check the result.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
$subscriptionId="Your subcription"
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred  -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId 


$resourceGroup = "Resource Group name"
$serviceBusName ="Service Bus Name"
$policyName = "Policy Name"
Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespaceKey  -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -Name $serviceBusName -AuthorizationRuleName $policyName
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I don't have the permission to set up an application id in the AD. I could talk to the domain admins to try to test this, but it will take me a little while.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the original login problem was some sort of problem with our AD configuration. Thanks for your help.