# How to get .publishsettings file

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

How to get .publishsettings file?
Now link from Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile redirect to portal.azure.com

old url:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings

Answer (score 1):

Add for Vikranth S

Classic Azure Portal **Retired**: [Microsoft announced Classic Azure portal update for classic portal users](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-portal-updates-for-classic-portal-users/?utm_content=buffer83e27&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) and **Vikranth S** also mentioned that Classic Azure portal has retired since **January 8, 2018.**  All functions will be available in the new portal.

The Azure powershell `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` try to get the publishing setting files that are only `intended and limited to manage Azure Service Management (ASM) resources` that has retired.

> Azure Management Certificates and **Publishing Setting files** (which is a file that contains the Management Certificates) are only `intended and limited to manage Azure Service Management (ASM) resources`, which means, resources from the Previous Azure Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com).

If you want to auto login with Azure powershell, you could use the following command. Detail steps you also could refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190914/azure-provisioning-without-manual-login/41216332#41216332).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId  "http://my-app" -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantid
```