# How to log in to Azure service principal

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, service-principal

1. `Connect-AzureRMAccount` doesn't work. I don't care. I don't want to run through the process of needing a PhD to understand why PowerShell never wants to work. So I'm going to use `Login-AzureRMAccount`
2. I've followed the docs. Of course it's inadequate so here I am.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-6.6.0

> "In order to get the service principal's credentials as the appropriate object, use the Get-Credential cmdlet. This cmdlet will display a dialog box to enter the service principal user ID and password into."

**Where do I even find my userID?** I followed another docs instructions on creating an SP and all I did was create an app. I got the SP object in PowerShell, all it did was give me a NAME of the SP .

Now that I understand what User ID is. HOW do I log in? I use `Login-AzureRmAccount` AND `Add-AzureRMAccount` and they BOTH say

```
$p = Get-Credential
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "XXXXXXXXXX" -Credential $p -TenantId "XXXXXXXXXXX"
Add(/Login)-AzureRmAccount : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the command below to log in as a service principal,it works fine on my side.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]

For more details, refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190914/azure-provisioning-without-manual-login/41216332#41216332).

Comment: what's my password? I never created a password to my app

Comment: @meowtho The password is the key in the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key), you could refer to it and create the key in the portal.

Comment: IT WORKED. BLESS YOUR SOUL THANKS

Comment: Had issus with Add-AzureRmAccount. Connect-AzAccount seems to do the things

Comment: In the output, did you got the subscription name? for me subscription is not coming, due to this, I am unable to access resources.

Comment: @Ashish-BeJovial You can set the subscription while you login using the switch : `Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant 'xxxx' -ServicePrincipal -Subscription 'xxxx'`

Answer (score 0):

The what you call userId is the **Application Id** (Also known as **ClientID**) of your service principal.

Answer (score 0):

The following really should work for you

```
$pscredential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -ApplicationId  "http://my-app" -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantid
```

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-6.6.0)

Comment: *hi. I already said I'm not using Connect-AzureRmAccount. Doesn't work. Login-AzureRmAccount is an alias so it should work the same

Comment: This worked for me  
$pscredential = Get-Credential  
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -TenantId "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx" -ServicePrincipal

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `Az Powershell` to login:

```
# Enter Service Principal's Object ID and Secret when prompted 
$Credential = Get-Credential

# Tenant ID
$TenantId = "XXX"
# Subscription ID
$SubscriptionId = "XXX"
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantId -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
```