# Connection to Azure Automation using own Service Principal with KEY

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-connect, azure-runbook

I'm creating a runbook with Azure Automation and using the cmdlets

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $Name
```

The connection is linked to a certificate that has a key. How do I provide a key with this connection cmdlet

```
    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal `
                   -EnvironmentName "AzureUSGovernment" `
                   -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
                   -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID `
                   -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint `
                   -ErrorAction Stop `
                   |Out-Null
```

Error:

```
AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: 'xxx', Please visit 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' and query for 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/8a09f2d7-8415-4296-92b2-80bb4666c5fc' to see configured keys] Trace ID: adfa5f5d-aaf2-4657-9e5f-1966ad540600 Correlation ID: 68f34f9b-b773-46ed-993e-e06ead5dd6b4 Timestamp: 2018-08-10 02:58:01Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in with service principal, you need to [create an authentication key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key) to do it, if you create an automation account, it will create an AD app and service principal automatically, more details refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719507/how-to-log-in-to-azure-service-principal/51721250#51721250).

Besides, when you getting the `SubscriptionId`, `TenantId`, `ApplicationId`, `CertificateThumbprint` via the command `$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $Name`. You should specify it with `$connection.FieldDefinitionValues.xxxxx`, like `-Tenant $connection.FieldDefinitionValues.TenantID`.

So your command should be:

```
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "your key" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($connection.FieldDefinitionValues.ApplicationID, $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal `
                   -EnvironmentName "AzureUSGovernment" `
                   -Tenant $connection.FieldDefinitionValues.TenantID `
                   -ApplicationId $connection.FieldDefinitionValues.ApplicationID `
                   -Credential $psCred `
                   -CertificateThumbprint $connection.FieldDefinitionValues.CertificateThumbprint
```