# Connect-AzAccount without prompt

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to login into Azure Portal by using

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

This code asks me for a prompt which I don't want, can we Auto login by using some simple config script.

Comment: Have you tried `$Credential = Get-Credential; Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential` ?

Comment: I tried but it asks for a prompt, the accepted answer below doesn't requires a prompt. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Joy said, you could login with the user account by credential which will no prompt, make sure your account doesn't enable the MFA.

```
$User = "xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "<tenant id>"
$subscription = "<subscription id>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $subscription
```

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890630/connect-azaccount-how-to-avoid-azure-device-authentification).

Comment: what happens if the user doesnt have any subscriptions linked to? thanks