# azure automation powershell runbook to get VM details in CSV file and export that CSV file to azure blob storage, can some one help on this

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-storage, runbook

I am running Azure automation PowerShell runbook script to get VM details in CSV file and export that CSV file to azure blob storage, but I am unable to capture the VM details through Azure automation PowerShell runbook script and keep it in blob storage

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$subscriptionId = "mySubID"
$reportName = "myReport.csv"
Select-AzSubscription $subscriptionId
$report = @()
$vms = Get-AzVM
$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} 
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, NicName, ApplicationSecurityGroup 
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        $info.VirtualNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
        $info.NicName = $nic.Name 
        $info.ApplicationSecurityGroup = $nic.IpConfigurations.ApplicationSecurityGroups.Id 
        $report+=$info 
    } 
$report | ft VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, NicName, ApplicationSecurityGroup 
$report | Export-CSV "AutomationFile123.csv"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "storagename" -StorageAccountKey "storagekey"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "conttainername" -File "AutomationFile123.csv" -Blob "AutomationFile123.csv"
```

Comment: Hi @Nares, Have you tried any PowerShell scripts?

Comment: Post this script in to your query

Comment: Could you please include error?

Comment: I do not have spesific error, but when i run this from Azure cloud shell it is executing successfully but when I do it from Azure automation runbook.. empty excel file placing in the blob (I mean vm details is not fetching the CSV file)

Comment: I can simplyfy my question:- Azure automation - How to use export-csv in azure automation using portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I tried the same script and got the same error like saving without Vm details.

**Console:**
[image]

The above error tells us that we are not connecting with our azure account.

I tried with  **`service principal login`** in the automation account it worked perfectly.

**Command:**

```
$Appid = "<Your app id>"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<App secret >" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "tenant id"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PWord
    # $Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "<subsciption Id>"
$reportName = "myReport.csv"
$report = @()
$vms = Get-AzVM
$publicIps = Get-AzPublicIpAddress 
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} 
foreach ($nic in $nics) { 
    $info = "" | Select VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, NicName, ApplicationSecurityGroup 
    $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id 
    foreach($publicIp in $publicIps) { 
        if($nic.IpConfigurations.id -eq $publicIp.ipconfiguration.Id) {
            $info.PublicIPAddress = $publicIp.ipaddress
            } 
        } 
        $info.OsType = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType 
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name 
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName 
        $info.Region = $vm.Location 
        $info.VmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        $info.VirtualNetwork = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-3] 
        $info.Subnet = $nic.IpConfigurations.subnet.Id.Split("/")[-1] 
        $info.PrivateIpAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress 
        $info.NicName = $nic.Name 
        $info.ApplicationSecurityGroup = $nic.IpConfigurations.ApplicationSecurityGroups.Id 
        $report+=$info 
    } 
$report | ft VmName, ResourceGroupName, Region, VmSize, VirtualNetwork, Subnet, PrivateIpAddress, OsType, PublicIPAddress, NicName, ApplicationSecurityGroup 
$report | Export-CSV "AutomationFile123.csv"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "storage name" -StorageAccountKey "Account key"
$copytoblob=Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "test" -File "AutomationFile123.csv" -Blob "AutomationFile123.csv"
$copytoblob
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - How to Connect-AzAccount in Powershell Core (without prompt)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335840/how-to-connect-azaccount-in-powershell-core-without-prompt)