# Powershell - Upload to an Azure blob container

Tags: azure, powershell, blobstorage

I have an Azure storage account with Blob containers and folders (also named containers?) within these blob containers. I have an Account Name and Account Key to access it and I can upload files using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. I have been searching for a simple script to upload files to a specific blob container but I have been able to find one. Uninstallig the RM-modules and installing the AZ-modules was already a challenge.  The examples all seem to be very complicated (security is not an issue for this project) and I just cannot get them to work and I am newby to the subject.

Can anyone share a simple line of powershell script with me to do this?

Comment: Could you help us here with some more information that Are you looking for a PowerShell script to copy the blobs from local to Azure storage account? or to copy the files from one blob container to another blob container inside  the storage account?

Comment: Thanks, it is meant to upload local files (vendor invoices in xml format) to an Axureblob storage. We receive xml-invoices from vendors. I convert/enrich them using powershell (xslt/regex) and then want to have them uploaded to Azure Blobstorage. All automatically when one of my colleagues places them in some local directory. I think the script that SrideviMachavarapu-MT provided will work fine if I can have it work without having to confirm my Microsoft login every time the script is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to upload files to a specific blob container by using below PowerShell script and got the result successfully:***

```
Connect-AzAccount

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext 
-StorageAccountName 'YourStorageAccountName' 
-StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' -Protocol Https

Set-AzStorageBlobContent 
-File "C:\Users\Downloads\YourFileName" `  //Your file path
-Container YourContainerName 
-Blob "YourFileName" `  
-Context $ctx
```

**The file got uploaded to the blob container successfully like below:**

[image]

**To confirm the above, check in the Portal whether the file is uploaded or not like below:**

[image]

Please **note** that, to run the above script you need Azure modules like **`Az.Accounts`** and **`Az.Storage`** modules. You can refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-8.0.0) to install the same.

**Reference:**

[Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs - Azure PowerShell - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell)

Comment: Appologies for my late response but I was in a three day course. The script works quite nicely. An addition is that 
1. It requests me to add -TenantID 'mytenantid' when I connect via Connect-AzAccount.
2. I continuously need to confirm my Microsoft login. It then gives me this browser screen and it continues: "Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab." I need to find out how I can add my username/password to the Connect-AzAccount-part.

Comment: You can refer this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61098097/connect-azaccount-without-prompt) to add your username/password to Connect-AzAccount automatically without prompts.

Comment: Thanks for the link. In particular the comment about not using MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) did the trick for me. It seems to be working great with the few tests I have done. Thanks. This will be very helpfull for us!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to know it helped :)