# Connecting Azure with PS: Please try logging in with different credentials or a different subscription ID

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

1) I open Azure portal with my user account john.smith@mycompany.com at subs id "111111111111111111111111111". I can successfully create new resource as I'm contributor.

2) I run Az command to create resource and connect with following.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "111111111111111111111111111"
```

ERROR:

```
Connect-AzAccount : The provided account john.smith@mycompany.com does not have access to 
subscription ID "111111111111111111111111111". Please try logging in with different 
credentials or a different subscription ID.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: This command is working ? `az account set --subscription ${AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}`

Comment: az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect-AzAccount - how to avoid azure device authentification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890630/connect-azaccount-how-to-avoid-azure-device-authentification)

Comment: I'm convinced that my code is correct since if I change Id to MSDN subs, it successfully connect.

Comment: Amit your link "Connect-AzAccount - how to avoid azure device authentification" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link it might help you if you haven't figured it out already

[Connect-AzAccount - how to avoid azure device authentification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890630/connect-azaccount-how-to-avoid-azure-device-authentification)