# How can i login to Azure using an account with MFA using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I am currently logging int Azure using

az login -u  -p ""

The issue is that the email is MFA and a verification code is needed to be entered in.
This login process is used for CICD. Is there a way I can automate this process without having to enter the verification code

Comment: You should be able to do this with a service principal that has the appropriate access (owners) to run all of the Powershell scripts.

Comment: is there some example i can follow ?

Comment: The example code below is a good one. Take a look at it and see if it works. I would also take a look at this one as well ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719507/how-to-log-in-to-azure-service-principal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your valuable suggestion and for directing in the right direction, @fmarz10.

> Service principals with various forms of credentials, such as passwords, secret keys, and certificates, can be used to do this.
> After adding the role you can automate login using
>
> ```
> $azureAplicationId ="Your Azure AD Application Id"
> $azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
> $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "strong password" -AsPlainText -Force
> $psCred = New-Object >System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
> Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  ->ServicePrincipal
> ```

**REFERENCES**

1. [Azure Service Principals](https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-service-principal/#:%7E:text=%20Creating%20an%20Azure%20Service%20Principal%20with%20Password,values%20ready%20to%20create%20the%20Azure...%20More%20)
2. [Sign in with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-7.5.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.6.0)
3. [Azure Provisioning - Without manual login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190914/azure-provisioning-without-manual-login/41216332#41216332)

Comment: Good stuff! Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Great @SwethaKandikonda-MT works well.